# Boinic server l2tp vpn

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn

I have the need to place an ubuntu server at a location remote to me and wish to have this server keep an l2tp VPN connection up to my local network.

Or put in a different way, I would need the Ubuntu server to initiate the VPN and make sure it stays connected all the time.

All the instructions I seem to find show how to set this up with a GUI. I wish to not have a GUI on this machine.

Looking for a guide/how to.